# Change client to server and server to client in socket.io (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sockets, connection

I know the title is so weird, but my problem is there.

Socket.io offers a big advantages which is establishing connection with clients even if clients are under firewalled local network.

This happens if the server has a public IP, and the clients connect on it.
In my case, the server is under a firewalled local network and the client has the public IP.

I thought about making a client in the server and a server in the client to establish a socket connection. Then I reuse the existing (opened) socket connection to connect a server in the client side and a client in the server side.

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like Inception. Joke aside, can't you make the server listen on an open port? you could use nginx to separate socket traffic from web and bind it to port 80.

Comment: It's not a good solution. It seems that I will have to modify the code in order to put the server instead of the client and a client instead of the server.

Comment: But I think it's not impossible to do what I posted. I saw the server socket contents and the client socket contents before and after connecting, and the changes can be made manually

Comment: you'll have the same problem, if your user is behind a firewall.